# NSArray ObjectAtIndex:0 --- get count?

Tags: uitableview, nsarray

I have an NSArray that I pass in through a delegate method:

```
- (void)didFinishParsing:(NSArray *)array {
    [self.myArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.myArray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

There's only one object in the `array` and I'd like the tableView row count to equal the amount of objects in the `array objectAtIndex:0`, but I cannot get the count. I have tried:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.myArray objextAtIndex:0] count];
}
```

How do I get the number of object inside the first (and only) object in my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the array at index 0 of self.myArray your syntax is correct. Is your `array` variable setup how you think it is?

The method call `addObjectsFromArray:` will add the contents of `array` to the end of `self.myArray`.

So in other words: `[array objectAtIndex:0]` will become `[self.myArray lastObject:]`

If you're having trouble running `count:` on `[self.myArray objectAtIndex:0]` or `[self.myArray lastObject]` then the object you're trying to count might be `nil`, empty, not an NSArray/Set as you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Hmm. Not really working. I alloc an object with a initWithDictionary method (myParsedObject) instead now, and pass that through in the "- (void)didFinishParsing:(MyParsedObject *)parsedObject" method, but I still cannot get the count for the number of objects contained inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an array within an array you should instead use

```
[self.myArray addObject: array];
```

This will add the array at the next index inside self.myArray. What you were doing previously with

```
[self.myArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
```

was adding the contents of `array` into `self.myArray` not adding `array` itself into `self.myArray`.